# How to parse DateTime in Locale other than english?

Tags: datetime, parsing, rust

Learning rust, I'm a bit stuck with `DateTime` parsing. I've already learned that there is a [chrono](https://crates.io/crates/chrono) crate which provides the functionality for parse/format `DateTime` ([docs](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/#formatting-and-parsing)). It even supports formatting in the desired locale in case `unstable-locales` feature is enabled. But somehow it doesn't support parsing of such datetimes.

In my case I would like to parse `10-Mai-23 10:15` which is a german version of `10-May-23 10:15`. Can someone point me to the right direction about how to parse this `DateTime`, please?

I've tried to run the following tests (after doing `cargo add chrono --features unstable-locales`)

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use chrono::prelude::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_en() {
        let timestr = "10-May-23 10:15";
        let dt = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(&timestr, "%d-%b-%y %H:%M");
        println!("en: dt={:?}", dt);
        assert!(dt.is_ok());
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_de() {
        let timestr = "10-Mai-23 10:15";
        let dt = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(&timestr, "%d-%b-%y %H:%M");
        println!("de: dt={:?}", dt);
        assert!(dt.is_ok());
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_de_localized() {
        let timestr = "10-Mai-23 10:15";
        let dt = (|| -> chrono::ParseResult<NaiveDateTime> {
            let mut parsed = chrono::format::Parsed::new();
            let items =
                chrono::format::StrftimeItems::new_with_locale("%d-%b-%y %H:%M", Locale::de_DE);
            chrono::format::parse(&mut parsed, &timestr, items)?;
            parsed.to_naive_datetime_with_offset(0)
        })();
        println!("de local: dt={:?}", dt);
        assert!(dt.is_ok());
    }
}
```

But without any luck. I've even crafted an own closure, which uses items with locale.

```
running 3 tests
test tests::test_parse_de ... FAILED
test tests::test_parse_de_localized ... FAILED
test tests::test_parse_en ... ok

failures:

---- tests::test_parse_de stdout ----
de: dt=Err(ParseError(Invalid))
thread 'tests::test_parse_de' panicked at src/main.rs:22:9:
assertion failed: dt.is_ok()
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

---- tests::test_parse_de_localized stdout ----
de local: dt=Err(ParseError(Invalid))
thread 'tests::test_parse_de_localized' panicked at src/main.rs:36:9:
assertion failed: dt.is_ok()


failures:
    tests::test_parse_de
    tests::test_parse_de_localized

test result: FAILED. 1 passed; 2 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```